# Readjust text inside of JList element

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a `JList`, the list is filled with the elements of a file, I want the text within the elements to be adjusted to the size of the list, increasing the height of the cell and giving line breaks.

[image]

How could I do it?

Comment: You mean the width of the displayed JList should fit the length of the text? What **do** you mean?

Comment: If the former, and your JList is a `JList<String>` then set the prototype String for the list by calling `jList.setPrototypeCellValue(....)` where `....` represents a String of the appropriate size.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"why answer and then delete?"* I read the question again after posting the answer & decided I'd given the right answer .. to the wrong question! The way I now read it, is that the OP wants variable height cells with word wrap in the list. OP: That might be achievable using HTML with a body width, but I did not have the time to check that out.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels OK.. I've had time to revisit the problem & confirm a HTML format cell renderer works as I expected. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: and excellent answer as always. 1+ and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the text within the elements to be adjusted to the size of the list

A list cell renderer (typically a `JLabel`) supports HTML formatting, so we can use styles to set a body width. The height of the cell will adjust accordingly. The middle list uses a renderer that is constrained to 100 px width.

[image]

That's three lists based on properties of the first thousand Unicode characters. Each list is as wide as it needs to be in order to display the widest string in the list model (however it is formatted for rendering).

Here is the MCVE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.Vector;

public class UnicodeNameList {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    UnicodeNameList() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));
        Vector<String> unicodeNames = new Vector<>();
        Vector<String> unicodeDir = new Vector<>();
        Vector<String> unicodeChar = new Vector<>();
        for (int ii=0; ii<1000; ii++) {
            unicodeChar.add(new String(Character.toChars(ii)));
            unicodeNames.add(Character.getName(ii));
            unicodeDir.add("" + Character.getDirectionality(ii));
        }
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(new JList(unicodeChar)), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        JList list = new JList(unicodeNames);
        LongListCellRenderer llcr = new LongListCellRenderer();
        list.setCellRenderer(llcr);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(new JList(unicodeDir)), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            UnicodeNameList o = new UnicodeNameList();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class LongListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        String pre = "<html><body style='width: 100px;'>";
        JLabel l = (JLabel)super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        String s = value==null ? "Null" : value.toString();
        l.setText(pre + s);
        return l;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you Andrew